# Why is pooled geoprocessing service not available via the ArcGIS Rest API?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-rest-api

I'm using ArcGIS Server 10.0.

I've published a pooled asynchronous python geoprocessing service. It works correctly using the Rest API.

When I configure the service not to be pooled, I can't access it via the Rest API anymore. I get the following error:
Service 'myService' of type 'GPServer' does not exist or is inaccessible. Error code: 404.

Is this normal?

Below the Pooling tab of my service configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's just not possible!
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/08/12/the-rest-api-cache/